# Headers on Adapter - How to add sections?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a single `listView` with two `adapter`s.  I use `MergeAdapter` to bring them to one list.  However, I want both `adapter`s to have a `header` because the data in both lists relate to two different things.  But `header`s generally are attached to a `ListView`, not an `adapter`.

I know there are a couple of methods you can `override` in `ArrayAdapter`, I think, where you can substitute a row as a sort-of header.  Is this the option I need to take?  If not, better options?

This is all I want to achieve.  Header, followed by `adapter` "1" with 10 rows.  Another Header, followed by `adapter` "2" with 10 rows.  There will always be 10 rows in each.

Comment: You could use a list of 22 items and give the 0 and the 11th position the layout of the header, but only because there will always be the same number of rows

Comment: That is what I was thinking.  It is a static list.  It will always use an SQL query with `LIMIT 10` on the back end.  What is best means of doing this?

Comment: I did it like that in an app I made and it worked ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `Override` `getItemViewType` in the `adapter` and simply make the header I was looking for as a specific item type.

Answer (score 1):

you may be able to do the following but I'm not sure.

```
adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addView(header);
adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter);
adapter.addView(header);
adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand, but look [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/), see if this can help you.